# Sticky header: sub menu doesn't show up

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, sticky

I tried to find an answer to this but nothing seems to apply to my case.

I have a header including an upper space (called "void" in my case) and a menu just below it.

When scrolling down, the header goes up and the menu sticks to the top of the screen as expected.

So far so good.

The problem is that this menu has a submenu. But this submenu only works when the menu is not sticked to the top of the screen.

Now, I know it's because the submenu should be "fixed" positioned too when the menu is "fixed" but in my case, it just doesn't work because then the submenu is fixed alright but it disappears behind the rest of the page, whatever z-index I give to it (or whatever z-index I give to any other component of the page, really).

So I feel like I tried everything I could possibly think of and I'm stuck.

I made a JSFiddle and you can test my script.
To replicate the bug, just hover the menu when the header is not stuck and then, after a scroll down, do the same again.
It will work when it's not stuck but the submenu won't show up when it is.

Thanks for your help.

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="void"></div>
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="block">
            <li class="item">xxxxx</li>
            <li class="item">xxxxx</li>
            <li class="item drop">Hover here
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="">submenu 1</a>
                    <a href="">submenu 2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">xxxxxx</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    width:100%;
    height:6000px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background: #ccc;
}

header{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index:1;
    height:146px;
}

.void{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}

.menu{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:54px;
    background:#aaa;
}

.menu ul{
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item{
    display:inline-block;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:100%;
    color:#41546F;
    line-height:54px;
    font-size:13px;
}

.block {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 140px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left:-40px;
    margin-top:0px;
    background:#21242b;
    padding:16px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
    color:#a2a9b9;
    line-height:32px;
}

.drop a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.drop:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 92){
        if (!$('.fixed').length){$('.menu').addClass('fixed');}
    } 
    else {
        if ($('.fixed').length){$('.menu').removeClass('fixed');}                  
    }     
});
```

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/3xnjeh01/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue there is the `overflow: hidden` on `.fixed`.
It is hiding the submenu, you just have to remove it.

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Mmm... It works very well thank you BUT. In my own web page, removing the overflow there prevents me from hovering the sub menu as it disappears as soon as I leave the upper menu item.For whatever reason, this isn't a problem with the JSFIddle though so technically you solved the case as I played it out here (thank you). I still keep this question open fo a while and will close it OR update it if I solved the issue or not in my real case scenario.

Comment: Do you have this page live to check? Probably there is something more there that I can help.

Comment: Yes, here is the link: https://www.phenotype.be/bonheur/v24/departements.php (the hoverable menu is in red right now)

Comment: PS: just for you to know, at this point of the dev, the page is only browsable for a window width greater than 840px. So be sure to have a larger width when testing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok. I see. So, looks like the `.shadow` element is the problem there because of its `z:index: 1000`. It is competing with the sibling `.top-menu`. You can add `z-index` for `.top-menu` with value 1001 or higher and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very very very much Azametzin. It crossed my mind as I already tried to lower the z-index of the "shadow", without any success though, so I just thought it wasn't the culprit. but I actually never thought of increasing the z-index of the ".top-menu" element instead. I didn't think it would make a difference as it felt like basically the same thing. Thanks!